# como remover o.php com o .htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess

Bom galera estou acostumado a chamar o seguinte link com meu apache:

```
index.php?variavel1=1&variavel2=2
```

Tem como eu fazer o meu .htaccess identificar o seguinte link:

```
index?variavel1=1&variavel2=2
```

E trocar por:

```
index.php?variavel1=1&variavel2=2
```

Dessa forma eu ocultaria o .php

Comment: Sim tem possível, pesquise sobre **url amigavel** pode ajudar muito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que esse pode ser o caminho:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Retirado daqui: [alexican.com](https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)

Comment: dei um olhada aqui e não estou entendendo muito bem. queria pegar os ? do meu url e trocar por .php

Comment: entao sua pergunta está um pouco confusa, pois o que entendi seria que você gostaria de remover o .php de suas Urls

Comment: bom o objetivo e esse mesmo, vou tentar me explicar melhor ok. Tentei usar o seu código, porem obtive o seguir erro: Internal Server Error estou tentando chamar o arquivo assim: 127.0.0.1/index

Comment: consegui aqui vlw ;)